# How can I do large permutations efficiently?

Tags: python

I'm in need of doing permutations on a list comprised of every value from 0 to 1, in 0.05 intervals.

I've already tried using itertools' permutations method (or function) but the program takes ages to get the permutation done and even crashes Spyder at it while I run it. I also need every number in each instance of the permutation to add up to 1 (example of this in the code snippet below). I can't even test the changes I make to the code since it would make my computer to stop working. Any suggestions?

```
weight.append(i for i in list(itertools.permutations(weights)) if sum(i)<=1.04 and sum(i)>=0.96)
```

I did a double sum check because the sum of the numbers didn't exactly result in 1, so I couldn't just try `if sum(i)==1`. This doesn't really append anything to the list I need it to append the results to, but that's a different issue.

Comment: This is what's crashing Spyder: `list(itertools.permutations(weights))`. There's no need to convert the generator returned by `premutations` to a list. The whole purpose of generators is to generate potentially infinite sequences _on demand_ without eating up all the RAM.

Comment: Besides the **obvious** mistake (`list(...)`), something doesn't seem right. All the permutations will have the same sum (*10.5* (if the last element (*1.0*) is included)), so the loop is kind of useless. what are you really trying to do?

Comment: This brute force algorithm is not the optimal solution to this problem.

Comment: @CristiFati you're absolutely right. Been thinking it wrong the whole time. I wanted every single possible combination of those numbers in a given length space. For example, if you had 3 spaces for the combination, one of those could be 0,0,1, another could be 1,0,0, another could be 0,0.95,0.05, etc. Thought the problem out wrongly. Could you point me out in the right direction for what I'm describing? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment revealed what you're after. It's not permutations, but *Cartesian product*. 
In *Python*, that "translates" to [[Python 3.Docs]: itertools.**product**(**iterables, repeat=1*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from itertools import product


def filter_values(values, min_sum=0, max_sum=100, count=3):
    for item in product(values, repeat=count):
        if min_sum <= sum(item) <= max_sum:
            yield item


def main():
    weights = [float(i) / 100 for i in range(0, 105, 5)]
    print("Weights: {:}\n".format(weights))

    filtered_weights = list(filter_values(weights, min_sum=0.96, max_sum=1.04))  # @TODO - cfati: !!! NOTA BENE: list(...) is for display purposes only! I guess its (disastrous) effects are quite familiar when it comes to large amounts of data !!!
    print("Filtering yielded {:d} elements".format(len(filtered_weights)))
    if (len(filtered_weights)):
        print("  First: {:}\n  Last: {:}".format(filtered_weights[0], filtered_weights[-1]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q056551640]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Weights: [0.0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1.0]
>
> Filtering yielded 231 elements
>   First: (0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
>   Last: (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
>
> Done.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Given your precisions to the question (in the comments), you could get all these "permutations" using a simple list comprehension:

```
combos = [ (x/20,y/20,(20-x-y)/20) for x in range(21) for y in range(21-x) ]

# 231 combinations:
#
# [(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 0.05, 0.95), (0.0, 0.1, 0.9), (0.0, 0.15, 0.85), ... 
#  ... (0.95, 0.0, 0.05), (0.95, 0.05, 0.0), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)]
```